# PHP MySQLi timeout

Tags: php, mysqli

today I've been creating a website. But I'm kinda.. stuck.

Here's what I do:

```
function getRank($rank)
{
    if ($stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare('SELECT * FROM users_ranks WHERE id = ?     LIMIT 1'))
    {   
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $rank);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

        return $row;
    }
}
```

My Database is correct. At my method, I use:

```
<?php 

    $att = array();
    $color = '';
    $font = '';
    $name = '';

while ($res = getRank($_SESSION['USER']['role']))
{
    $color = $res['color'];
    $font = $res['font'];
    $name = $res['name'];
}

echo '<text style="font-family: ' . $name . '; color: ' . $color . ';">';


echo $_SESSION['USERNAME'];

echo '</text>';

?>
```

When it runs the code, I always get this error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp_new\htdocs\iondelt\global.php on line 80
```

The line:

```
$row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

I'm not a mysqli master, please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($res = getRank($_SESSION['USER']['role']))
```

That looks like an infinite loop. How will $res ever end up as false in order for the loop to exit?

Comment: Yeah I forgot it's an array which just can be accessed with [], solved now, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`get_result()` was introduced in PHP 5.4.0 and requires mysqlnd. Is it needed? Try

```
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
```